# Show contents of table but limit to those matching signed-in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my quiz game Rails project, I have a table for "Participations" that stores information on the user, the quiz category, and the quiz score after a user completes the test.

```
class CreateParticipations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :participations do |t|
     t.references :user
     t.string :category
     t.boolean :finished, default: false
     t.integer :current_question_index, default: 0
     t.integer :score, default: 0

     t.timestamps
  end
 end
```

end

In my user.rb, I specify an association that a user `has_many :participations`, which allows a user to play multiple quizzes while storing categories/scores in the table.

If I want to show a user a table of his results (so return all Participations results, but only for those that match the user) in a view, can I call that without generating a new controller?

Comment: How does the `Participation` associate to a `Quiz`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do like below

```
#in the controller action
@user_participations = Participation.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

and just call `@user_participations` in the view.

Answer (score 1):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :participations, path: "results", only: :index #-> url.com/users/:user_id/results
end

#app/controllers/participations_controller.rb
class ParticipationsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @user = User.find params[:user_id]
      @participations = @user.participations
   end
end

#app/views/participations/index.html.erb
<% @participations.each do |participation| %>
   <%= participation.score %>
<% end %>
```

--

If you have your `associations` set up correctly, you should be using the associative method (`@user.participations`), which will basically do what `Pavan` has suggested:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :participations
end

#app/models/participation.rb
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Users controller
  has_many :participations

  def participations
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     @participations = @users.participations.build(params[:participation_id])
  end 

end

ParticipationsController
  belongs_to :user
```

In your routes file you can create the route    by 
    `GET 'users/:id/participations', to: 'users#participations', as:  'user_participations'`

That will give you a user_participations_path route
So if you wanted to link to it you could add
    <%= link_to 'Show user games!',  user_participations_path(@participations.user) %>

Then in views/users/participations

```
<% @participations.each do |participation| %>
  <%= participation.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

Let me know how you go!

**EDIT**

Please not that the has_many and belongs_to declarations should be in the `user.rb` and `participation.rb` models respectively. Thanks to @richpeck for picking up the mistake.

Comment: I had to downvote because you included `has_many` in controller

Comment: Ahh thanks for the pick up @richpeck A lapse in concentration. I'll edit it